# How do I install JDBC to work in Java 8 on Debian 10?

Tags: java, mysql-connector

I'm trying to connect into MySQL database on Java 8 using this code, but I'm getting an exception that JDBC driver class was not found. What is the solution for Debian 10? java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

```
import java.sql.*; 

class MysqlCon {

 public static void main(String args[]) {  
    try {  
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
           "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo","root","root");  
       //here sonoo is database name, root is username and password  
       Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
       ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
       while(rs.next())  
       System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3));  
       con.close();  
    } catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
    }  
 }  
}
```

Comment: Put the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` jar on your classpath

Comment: Add the MySQL JDBC driver to your classpath. You can get it (the jar file) from here (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) or using Maven, or other.

Comment: BTW, you haven't needed `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` since **Java 6**.

Comment: The problems still remains after adding mysql-connector-java 8.0.19 into my project as a maven dependency..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling your java program from command line you should add additional parameter -cp or -classpath with a reference to the JDBC library jar file.

Example:

```
# Java directory 
export JAVA_DIR="/usr/java8_64"

# Classpath
export CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/mysql-connector-java.jar"

# Start application
${JAVA_DIR}/bin/java -jar <MY_JAR_FILE_NAME> -classpath ${CLASSPATH}
```